# Threading methods within a Class in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working with Python Tkinter on Windows. My goal is to have a SQL query run in the background of an animated GUI loading screen. However, I can't get the threading figured out. The threads run sequentially instead of in parallel.

I have commented out the code that I thought would work. The code as is will produce a loading screen, but it does not run _data_run at the same time. If you replace the run(self) statement with the commented out piece, the loading screen will not populate at all. I know that the parentheses after the method force the threads to run one after the other - how do I get the threads to execute within the class without the method parentheses? Should I be creating another class to run the _data_run function in?

I am brand new to tkinter and a novice with Python. Any best practices or recommendations you have are appreciated as well.

```
import tkinter as tk
import threading

colorfade =['#0076B6','#127FBB','#2489C0','#3693C5','#489DCA','#5BA6D0','#6DB0D5','#7FBADA','#91C4DF','#A3CEE4','#B6D7EA','#C8E1EF','#DAEBF4','#ECF5F9','#FFFFFF']


class LoadingFrame (tk.Frame):
      def __init__(self, master):
            super().__init__(master)
            self.state = 0
            self.titlelabel = tk.Label(self, text = 'LOADING',  font = ('Calibri',60),fg = blue,  bg = blue)
            self.titlelabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
            self.pack(expand = True)
            self.run()


      def run(self):
            t1 = threading.Thread(target = self._animate())
            t2 = threading.Thread(target = self._data_run())
            t1.start
            t2.start

#      def run(self):
#            t1 = threading.Thread(target = self._animate)
#            t2 = threading.Thread(target = self._data_run)
#            t1.start
#            t2.start

      def _data_run(self):
            print('data run started')
            #SQL Query would go here
            self.state = 1
            print('data run complete')

      def _fade_in(self, j):
            self.titlelabel['fg']  = colorfade[j]

      def _fade_out(self, j):
            self.titlelabel['fg']  = colorfade[14-j]

      def _animate(self):
            for i in range(10):
                  for j in range(15):
                        self.after(20,self._fade_in(j))
                        self.titlelabel.update()
                  for j in range(15):
                        self.after(20,self._fade_out(j))
                        self.titlelabel.update()
                  self.titlelabel.update()
blue = '#000077'                 
window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('1750x950')
#window.geometry('1200x900')
window['bg'] = blue
window.title('Frame')
lf = LoadingFrame(window)

lf['bg'] = blue


window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your commented-out version looks more correct to me. But remember that `t1.start` is a function, so to make it do anything, you have to call it: `t1.start()`. Same for `t2.start`.

Comment: @kevin thank you!! was banging my head against a wall. If you submit an answer, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your commented-out code came close to working -- but you need to call `start` to make the threads start.

```
  def run(self):
        t1 = threading.Thread(target = self._animate)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target = self._data_run)
        t1.start()
        t2.start()
```